# User id and password window popups everytime

Tags: tridion

We are using Tridion 5.3.

We have recently added new Content Manager Server in our DEV environment.

When we access Tridion GUI from Content Manager server everything goes right.

But when we try to access Content Manager Server from client machine, it asks for user id and Password again and again and finally user is getting locked.

Can anyone show us the way to debug this issue, does this related to domain of the server and client, they should be in same domain ? If different domain then once the password is provided it should work and should not ask it again.

Thanks.

Comment: Provide some more info about your setup: Are you using LDAP, are both machines in the same domain? Are you trying with domain user?

Answer (score 2):

The repeat popup usually occurs when your client machine is logged on to a different domain from the user Tridion is trying to authenticate.

When you input your login info, try putting in the name of the domain in the user name, e.g. SDL\user123